# SQL Query: Update substring in column matching with another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a address column has values `+` in postal code. But + could be anywhere in the column (Street name, city) but I need to identity only postal code in the address with another column called `Postal_Code` and remove `+`.

> It is going to be hard sql query to identify `+` in postal code and
>   remove but don't know how to do?

I already remove `+` from `Postal_Code` column.

Table Example

```
POSTAL_CODE             FORMATTED_ADDRESS
T2E 8N6                 #6, 1435-40th Ave NE #6 Calgary AB  T2E+8N6 Canada
23401                   9 Abolaji Street Mafoluku +23401 Oshodi Lagos State Nigeria
234-01                  6 Force Road, Square Race Course +234-01 Lagos, Nigeria Lagos State
86 163453               Daqing Oilfield Co.Ltd Ranghulu 86+163453 Daqing CHN
```

Comment: Are you looking update rows that are selected with something along the lines of: `select * from my_table where FORMATTED_ADDRESS like '%+' + POSTAL_CODE + '%`?

Comment: Do you want to UPDATE the FORMATTED_ADDRESS and remove those `+` if it's in front of the matching POSTAL_CODE?  Or just SELECT them without the `+` ?

Comment: @LukStorms update formatted_address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems hard in MS SQL Server.
(this would be so much easier with a regexp_replace function...)

Anyway....

Example snippet:

```
declare @YourTable table (POSTAL_CODE varchar(30), FORMATTED_ADDRESS varchar(1000));

insert into @YourTable (POSTAL_CODE, FORMATTED_ADDRESS) values
('T2E 8N6','#6, 1435-40th Ave NE #6 Calgary AB  T2E+8N6 Canada'),
('23401', '9 Abolaji Street Mafoluku +23401 Oshodi Lagos State Nigeria'),
('234-01', '6 Force Road, Square Race Course +234-01 Lagos, Nigeria Lagos State'),
('86 163453', 'Daqing Oilfield Co.Ltd Ranghulu 86+163453 Daqing CHN'),
(NULL, 'foo +1234 bar'),
('12345', 'bar 12345+ baz');

UPDATE @YourTable
SET FORMATTED_ADDRESS = 
    REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
          REPLACE(FORMATTED_ADDRESS, 
             '+'+POSTAL_CODE, POSTAL_CODE),
             POSTAL_CODE+'+', POSTAL_CODE),
             REPLACE(POSTAL_CODE,' ','+'), POSTAL_CODE)
WHERE POSTAL_CODE IS NOT NULL
AND (
     FORMATTED_ADDRESS LIKE CONCAT('%+', POSTAL_CODE, '%') OR
     FORMATTED_ADDRESS LIKE CONCAT('%', POSTAL_CODE, '+%') OR
     (POSTAL_CODE LIKE '%[ ]%' AND FORMATTED_ADDRESS LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(POSTAL_CODE,' ','+'), '%'))
);


SELECT * FROM @YourTable;
```

Comment: your code working perfectly good. only one condition it is not working when `Mafoluku 23401+ Oshodi `. Front `+` working but not rear `+` not

Comment: And also if your update state setting `NULL` if POSTAL_CODE is null

Comment: @James123 No longer selecting the empty postal_codes. And now also with + after it.

Comment: @James123 it's been simplified.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some `REPLACE` statements:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET FORMATTED_ADDRESS = REPLACE(
        REPLACE(FORMATTED_ADDRESS, REPLACE(POSTAL_CODE, ' ', '+'), POSTAL_CODE), 
        '+'+POSTAL_CODE, 
        POSTAL_CODE)
FROM YourTable
```

You can test the results of this query by `SELECT`ing first:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
        REPLACE(FORMATTED_ADDRESS, REPLACE(POSTAL_CODE, ' ', '+'), POSTAL_CODE), 
        '+'+POSTAL_CODE, 
        POSTAL_CODE) AS NEW_FORMATTED_ADDRESS,
        FORMATTED_ADDRESS
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: How to check this query works to see not breaking anything.??

Comment: Check the edit, you can see what the `UPDATE` will do.